# Postgres Sql query digits.digits.digits

Tags: sql, postgresql

just wondering how would I write a Postgres query to find something like Appleweb/54.425.1 but the digits after the / can be a few digits long for example /521.24.134 or just as Appleweb/15.1 obviously the numbers are random. I understand you would have to use a `\.` to represent the decimal/full stop

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression:

```
where col ~ '/[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*$'
```

This says that the string ends with:

1. a hyphen
2. followed by 1 or more digits
3. followed by a period and more digits, repeated any number of times (including zero times).